# Event time mismatches when creating new events

Tags: php, timezone, google-calendar-api, google-api-php-client

I have an issue with the dateTime start/end when I add an event to my calendar.

Here is the code I use:

```
$event = new Google_Service_Calendar_Event(array(
  'summary' => 'event title',
  'description' => 'event description',
  'start' => array(
    'dateTime' => '2017-02-05T00:00:00-08:00',
    'timeZone' => 'Europe/Paris',
  ),
  'end' => array(
    'dateTime' => '2017-02-05T00:00:00-13:00',
    'timeZone' => 'Europe/Paris',
  )
));

$event = $cal->events->insert($room_calendar_id, $event);
```

This code should add an event in my calendar, starting at 08:00, ending 13:00. Fact is, the event is added starting at 10:00, ending at 15:00.
It add 2 hours to the dateTime.

Do you think that the error comes from the timezone ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are confusing the local time for the time zone offset.

```
2017-02-05T00:00:00-08:00   =>  2017-02-05T08:00:00+01:00

2017-02-05T00:00:00-13:00   =>  2017-02-05T13:00:00+01:00
```

Both values should have a `+01:00` offset, because that is the UTC offset in effect at the time of the event in `Europe/Paris`.

Comment: Paris uses `+01:00` during standard time, and `+02:00` during summer time, for daylight saving. [See here](https://www.timeanddate.com/time/zone/france/paris).  The dates you gave are in +1, not +2.  Also, Google's API only requires a time zone (`Europe/Paris`) for *recurring* events, and you should *not* specify an offset at all in that case (since some occurrences might be in +1 and some might be in +2).

Comment: So, to recap - if you are talking about a single event, include an offset, and the time zone is optional.  For recurring events, omit the offset, and the time zone is required.  [Reference here](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/events/insert#start.dateTime).

Comment: I tried to add an event with a start time ex : 2017-02-05T08:00:00, timezone Europe\Paris. The event added started at 10:00. But anyway, I fixed the issue by comparing my local time with UTC. So during summer time the result is +2 and during winter time it's +1. That's good for me. Thanks